# login success page is not loading after authentication facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to get get user details from facebook using facebook sdk 5.
login page is loading and asking for login with facebook now when i am clicking on link its redirecting me to facebook and asking to allow share details i am clicking allow and then its redirecting to call back page but problem is callback page is keep loading after some time browser is showing
**The connection has timed out**
 **The server at website.com is taking too long to respond.**

Below is the screen shot and code i am using

[image: The connection has timeout]

```html
<?php
 
session_start();
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);
  
 $redirect = 'https://website.com/fb2/login.php';


 # Create the login helper object
 $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

 # Get the access token and catch the exceptions if any
 try {
   $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
   // When Graph returns an error
   echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
   // When validation fails or other local issues
   echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
 }

 # If the 
 if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
   // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
    // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] 
    // But we shall we the same page

  // Sets the default fallback access token so 
  // we don't have to pass it to each request
  $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

  try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,name');
    $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
  }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }


  // Print the user Details
  echo "Welcome !<br><br>";
  echo 'Name: ' . $userNode->getName().'<br>';
  echo 'User ID: ' . $userNode->getId().'<br>';
  echo 'Email: ' . $userNode->getProperty('email').'<br><br>';

  $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userNode->getId().'/picture?width=200';
  echo "Picture<br>";
  echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br>";
  
 }else{
  $permissions  = ['email'];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect,$permissions);
  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
 }
```

Comment: In order to debug and locate the problem try to minimize the functions calls and simply replace them with an "echo 'test - step1';"... step2...

Comment: Thank you sir i will try this option

Comment: Your screenshot and the code don’t match. In your code, the redirect_uri ends `/fb2/login.php`, but in your screenshot the code parameter is passed to the `index.php`

Comment: Sorry sir  i have modified the code after puting here actual code is login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out it was hosting issue , hosting servers where blocking internal requests which was causing this error.